# How Do I Implement an Admin Role With Rails Clearance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rubygems, authorization, clearance

I want an admin role so that I can access some RESTful states while my users cannot. I'm using Clearance but there is no longer a page on their wiki for how to implement an admin role for Clearance. Does anyone have it working on Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success with [Aegis](https://github.com/makandra/aegis). It doesn't guarantee Rails 3 compatibility but I haven't had any issues using it with Rails 3 (3.0.5).